# How to detect that a member function has specific function, taking specific arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I already have SFINAE code that detects whether a given member function exists AND can accept an instance of a specific type.

I'm trying to detect when there's a specific member function that takes as it's argument a NON-REFERENCE.

Example code

```
template<typename TYPE_T>
class HasSwapMemberImpl
{
    /*
     * This uses the compilers type deduction magic to ensure that there's SOME swap function
     * that's a member of CLASS_T, that can be passed an instance of CLASS_T, in some fashion.
     * This doesn't determine that the argument for the function is a reference.
     */
    template <typename CLASS_T>
    static auto test_compatible_swap_function_exists(CLASS_T * p) -> decltype(p->swap(*static_cast<CLASS_T*>(nullptr)), boost::true_type());

    /*
     * If no substitutions can satisfy p->swap(*static_cast<CLASS_T*>(nullptr)
     * we end up here as fallback.
     */
    template<typename>
    static boost::false_type test_compatible_swap_function_exists(...);

public:
    typedef decltype(test_compatible_swap_function_exists<TYPE_T>(nullptr)) type;
    static const bool value = type::value;
};

/**
 * \brief This MetaProgramming helper class determines if there exists a method named "swap" in the ARG_T type, that takes ARG_T as an argument.
 *
 * If ARG_T.swap(ARG_T) is a valid function, then HasSwapMember inherits from boost::true_type. Else it inherits from boost::false_type.
 */
template<typename ARG_T>
struct HasSwapMember : public HasSwapMemberImpl<ARG_T>::type { };
```

This works for several dozen test cases that I've written, so I'm not in need of any assistance here.

Instead, what I'm trying to do is detect a situation like this

```
struct NonReferenceSwap
{
    void swap(NonReferenceSwap) {}
};

struct ReferenceSwap
{
    void swap(ReferenceSwap &) {}
};
```

I want some metaprogramming helper, MetaHelperType, such that MetaHelperType inherits from boost::true_type, but MetaHelperType causes the compiler to error out with a message like "Swap functions must take reference arguments!"

Or, in other words:

```
MetaHelperType<ReferenceSwap>; // IS A boost::true_type
MetaHelperType<NoSwapFunction>; // IS A boost::false_type
MetaHelperType<NonReferenceSwap>; // Compiler error
```

Why do I want this? It's a nonsense concept to try to call foo.swap(bar), when bar will be passed as a value. My organization has a lot of novice c++ programmers, and we want to be able to catch this mistake immediately, and not find out someone forgot the & 2 months later.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, so not all c++11 features are available. The code above does work properly though, so at least those features work as expected.

Is this possible? If so, what minimum version of C++ is needed? C++11, C++14, C++17?

Comment: OT: `*static_cast<CLASS_T*>(nullptr)` can be replaced by `std::declval<CLASS_T&>()`.

Comment: Not in my environment. We use VS 2010 plus STLPort. STLPort doesn't support C++11 standard library stuff. (and we're using an out of date version of boost) Sorry for not mentioning that in the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following for exact signature check:

```
#include <cstdint>

#define DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(traitsName, funcName, signature)               \
    template <typename U>                                                   \
    class traitsName                                                        \
    {                                                                       \
    private:                                                                \
        template<typename T, T> struct helper;                              \
        template<typename T>                                                \
        static std::uint8_t check(helper<signature, &funcName>*);           \
        template<typename T> static std::uint16_t check(...);               \
    public:                                                                 \
        static                                                              \
        constexpr bool value = sizeof(check<U>(0)) == sizeof(std::uint8_t); \
    }

DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(has_ref_swap, T::swap, void (T::*)(T&));
DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(has_value_swap, T::swap, void (T::*)(T));
```

And then, you can write your helper check:

```
template <typename T>
struct MetaHelperType_impl
{
    static_assert(!has_value_swap<T>::value,
                  "Incorrect implementation of T::swap, "
                  "signature should be void T::swap(T&) instead of T::swap(T)");

    using type = std::conditional_t<has_ref_swap<T>::value,
                                    boost::true_type,
                                    boost::false_type>;
};

template <typename T>
using MetaHelperType = typename MetaHelperType_impl<T>::type;
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/szu4f3)

Comment: This can positively identify situations where there is a T::swap(T) versus T::swap(T&)? I've been messing with this code for a couple days, and I've used that technique, but wasn't able to get it to detect the difference. Am I missing something?

Comment: @jonesmz: Yes, it checks exact signature. Most of the time, it is a too strong requirement (in my example, `swap` is required to return `void`) as cv qualifier should match, return type should match which is not necessary required in generic code.

Answer (score 0):

Get swap's member function pointer and cast it into the proper signature you're expecting. Together with enable_if you can check if this cast fails or not:

```
template <typename T>
struct swap_signature { typedef void(T::*type)(T&); };

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_swappable : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_swappable<T,typename std::enable_if<std::is_member_function_pointer<
decltype(static_cast<typename swap_signature<T>::type>(&T::swap))>::value>::type> : std::true_type {};
```

Then you can test:

```
is_swappable<ReferenceSwap>::value // true
is_swappable<NonReferenceSwap>::value // false
```